# stub a request that is based on an update version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm setting all of my rspec tests, they work just fine, but some of them include a call to an API. Therefore, for these tests, I stub the request.

Unfortunately, request looks like this :

```
stub_request(:get, "https://api.sandbox.mangopay.c['my datas']").
      with(:body => "{}",
           :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Authorization'=>'', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby', 'X-Mangopay-Client-User-Agent'=>'{"bindings_version":"3.0.21","lang":"ruby","lang_version":"2.3.0 p0 (2015-12-25)","platform":"x86_64-linux","uname":"Linux wolf-N751JK 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"}'})
    stub_request(:post, "https://api.sandbox.mangopay.com/v2.01/oauth/token").
      with(:body => "grant_type=client_credentials",
           :headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'Authorization'=>'Basic a3Jhd2RzYXM6eWtVdEdiUHU5NzJBRjc2cEx0YjBLRHJoQTZrMTBCTDVvY3I2ZFBRalpqS1p1RDBlWm4=', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'})
```

Notice this part:

```
Linux wolf-N751JK 4.4.0-45-generic #66-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19 14:12:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I assume it is linked to my ubunutu version, which means that everytime I update my software, I'll have to change each and every stub. Is there a way to bypass this ?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to take a step back and think about what is making these requests. Is it some method? Stub that method instead. If it proves tricky, extract the logic into a wrapper, such as a new class, and stub its methods instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just not specifying the `X-Mangopay-Client-User-Agent` header?